# Canvas Images does not Persist while using KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am using Kinetic JS to build a small game in which the cars run on the track. I have used an Image for the Grass but trying to build the road all by myself. My problem is that whenever I run the Project the Black patch of Road Flashes and then Disappears and the grass appears whereas I need the road to be built on grass. Please Help. I have Shared the Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/aKh7V/embedded/result/

I have also mentioned the code below as follows:-

```
/*
Declaration of Road,Since the Road will be in 
both the directions I would be making an algorithm 
to get the road on the canvas and
the the car onto it.
*/
function Car(){}

Car.prototype={
    x:0,
    y:0,
    position:0,
    driver:0,
    booster:true,
    positionNext:0,
    getPosition : function(){return this.position;},
    setPosition : function(position){this.position=position;},
    getDriver : function(){return this.driver;},
    setDriver : function(driver){this.driver},
    getBooster : function(){return this.booster;},
    setBooster : function(booster){this.booster=booster;},
    getPositionNext : function(){return this.positionNext;},
    setPositionNext : function(positionNext){this.positionNext=positionNext;},
    drive : function(newPosition){
        /*Code to steer the car to the new box. Either Animate or keep Dynamic*/}
};

/*Making the Booster Class with Appropriate Getters and Setters*/
function Booster(){}
Booster.prototype={
    position:0,
    x:0,
    y:0,
    getX : function(){return this.x;},
    setX : function(x){this.x=x;},
    getY : function(){return this.y;},
    setY : function(y){this.y=y;},
    getPosition : function(){return this.position;},
    setPosition : function(position){this.position=position;}  
};

/*Road Block Class*/
function Road(){}
Road.prototype={
    x:0,
    y:0,
    bomb:false,
    booster:false,
    position:0,
    getX : function(){return this.x;},
    setX : function(x){this.x=x;},
    getBomb : function(){return this.bomb;},
    setBomb : function(bomb){this.bomb=bomb;},
    getBooster : function(){return this.booster;},
    setBooster : function(booster){this.booster=booster;},
    getPosition : function(){return this.position;},
    drawRoadPatch : function(roadLayer,stage){
        var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x:0,
            y:0,
            width:100,
            height:100,
            fill:'black'
        });
        roadLayer.add(rect);
        stage.add(roadLayer);
    }
};

/*Grass For Background*/
function Grass(){}
Grass.prototype={
    grassImage:'',
    grassX:0,
    grassY:0,
    grassWidth:1000,
    grassHeight:500,
    getGrassX : function(){return this.grassX;},
    setGrassX : function(x){this.grassX=x;},
    getGrassY : function(){return this.grassY},
    setGrassY : function(y){this.grassY=y},
    getWidth : function(){return this.grassWidth;},
    setWidth : function(width){this.grassWidth=width;},
    getHeight : function(){return this.grassHeight;},
    setHeight : function(height){this.grassHeight=height;},

    /*Grass Utility Functions*/
    drawGrass : function(background,stage,image){
        image.onload=function(){
        var grass = new Kinetic.Image({
            x:this.grassX,
            y:this.grassY,
            image:image,
            width:this.grassWidth,
            height:this.grassHeight
            });
        background.add(grass);
        stage.add(background);
        }
    },
    changeBackgroud : function(background,stage,image){
      //This can be used to change the backgroud of page  
    }

};





/*Declaring the Stage*/
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    width:1000,
    height:500,
    container:'container'
    });

/*Defining the assets (Images)*/
var backgroundImage = new Image();
var roadImage = new Image();
/*Defining the Layer (Layers)*/
var background = new Kinetic.Layer();
var roadLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var backgrass = new Grass();
var road = new Road();
/*Drawing Functions*/
backgrass.drawGrass(background,stage,backgroundImage);
road.drawRoadPatch(roadLayer,stage);



/*Image for Backgroud*/
backgroundImage.src='https://c9.io/shivkumarganesh/kiectcars/workspace/images/grass.jpg';
```

Just run the above code, you would understand the problem. There is a black flicker which I wat to be on grass as road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed...**

Your backgroundImage was being used in drawGrass() before it was fully loaded by backgroundImage.src.

I moved all your scene setup into a backgroundImage.onload callback function and all is fixed.

Here is reworked code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/GyrXr/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kinetic-v4.3.3.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

/*Road Block Class*/
function Road(){}
Road.prototype={
    x:0,
    y:0,
    bomb:false,
    booster:false,
    position:0,
    getX : function(){return this.x;},
    setX : function(x){this.x=x;},
    getBomb : function(){return this.bomb;},
    setBomb : function(bomb){this.bomb=bomb;},
    getBooster : function(){return this.booster;},
    setBooster : function(booster){this.booster=booster;},
    getPosition : function(){return this.position;},
    drawRoadPatch : function(roadLayer,stage){
        var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x:0,
            y:0,
            width:100,
            height:100,
            fill:'black'
        });
        roadLayer.add(rect);
        stage.add(roadLayer);
    }
};

/*Grass For Background*/
function Grass(){}
Grass.prototype={
    grassImage:'',
    grassX:0,
    grassY:0,
    grassWidth:1000,
    grassHeight:500,
    getGrassX : function(){return this.grassX;},
    setGrassX : function(x){this.grassX=x;},
    getGrassY : function(){return this.grassY},
    setGrassY : function(y){this.grassY=y},
    getWidth : function(){return this.grassWidth;},
    setWidth : function(width){this.grassWidth=width;},
    getHeight : function(){return this.grassHeight;},
    setHeight : function(height){this.grassHeight=height;},

    /*Grass Utility Functions*/
    drawGrass : function(background,stage,image){
        var grass = new Kinetic.Image({
            x:this.grassX,
            y:this.grassY,
            image:image,
            width:this.grassWidth,
            height:this.grassHeight
            });
        background.add(grass);
        stage.add(background);
    },
    changeBackgroud : function(background,stage,image){
      //This can be used to change the backgroud of page  
    }

};

/*Declaring the Stage*/
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    width:1000,
    height:500,
    container:'container'
    });

/*Defining the assets (Images)*/
// after waiting for the backgroundImage to load...!
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.onload=function(){
    var roadImage = new Image();
    /*Defining the Layer (Layers)*/
    var background = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var roadLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var backgrass = new Grass();
    var road = new Road();
    /*Drawing Functions*/
    backgrass.drawGrass(background,stage,backgroundImage);
    road.drawRoadPatch(roadLayer,stage);
}
backgroundImage.src='http://c9.io/shivkumarganesh/kiectcars/workspace/images/grass.jpg';

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```